# permanent redirect on wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-301

I've got a web site based on wordpress, I need to temporarily hide the web site.
I thought about using a PHP 301 redirect. I tried to put at the begining of index.php and xmlrpc.php without success. How does wordpress file-structure works?

Tnx

Giuseppe

Answer (score 2):

I've used this for redirects in the same purpose:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/

I put the temporary html-file that I wanted to display in a folder which was placed in the same place as the main index.php file.

Comment: Bump for this. Redirection is a nice plugin. Easy to manage your 301's :)

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to hide a website under development, block search engines in Dashboard/Settings/Privacy and use something like [WordPress › Absolute Privacy « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/absolute-privacy/) to disable RSS feeds and redirect to a static page you choose.